# The item you have requested is not available in any store

Tags: iphone, app-store, itunes, itunes-store

Greetings for the day.

I am able to open my app on Appstore. Through appstore I am also able to view in iTunes. But when I try to open direct iTunes link the message comes "The item you have requested is not available in xx store".

Note: My app is available for all stores & I repeat I am able to view in iTunes from appstore url.

Any idea why the direct link is not getting open?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an App Store. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am done with the ultimate solution.

What I did is: I changed the url.

I replace the url with the same url that I was able to open from the Appstore via view in iTunes.

This worked for me ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Is the url encoded?? url sometimes you use might have some mistakes.please check da.

Comment: yes, I do check the url multiple times, with device browser & mac browser but everytime got the same result :(